# Decrementing a uint field in c# mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to decrement a `uint` field from 1 to 0. Due to the way `Inc` works, I do have to cast it to an int, as such:

```
UpdateDefinition<Student> updateDef = Builders<Student>.Update.Inc(s => (int)s.Grade, -1);
GetStudentCollection().UpdateOne(s => s.Id == 12345, updateDef);
```

This works perfectly fine when I increment with `1` instead of `-1`, but when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32.
   at System.Convert.ToUInt32(Int32 value)
```

I have debugged the retrieved `Student` from that LINQ query and confirmed that `s.Grade` was at `1` before I attempted the decrement. Since `0` is within valid `uint` range, I don't get why it errored out like that.

What could I be missing and how can I get around casting the `uint`? (As in a solution besides "don't use uints")

Comment: Why are you casting at all?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Because `Inc` requires that I do so. It won't accept a `uint` argument.

Answer (score 1):

`Inc` in `UpdateDefinitionBuilder` is defined as:

```
public UpdateDefinition<TDocument> Inc<TField>(FieldDefinition<TDocument, TField> field, TField value);
```

The same type `TField` is used for field definition (`FieldDefinition<TDocument, TField>`) and for increment value, that's why following expression will not compile:

```
Builders<Student>.Update.Inc(x => x.Grade, -1);
```

By casting `x.Grade` to `int`, you could cheat a compiler but not a MongoDB Driver. Eventually the driver will try to cast value of `-1` to model type of `uint` which throws `OverflowException`.

If you want to keep data type of `uint` for `Grade` property and to have possibility to decrement it, the only way I can figure out is to bypass strongly typed `UpdateDefinition` and to use raw `$inc` operator:

```
GetStudentCollection().UpdateOne(s => s.Id == 12345, "{ $inc: { Grade: -1 } }");
```